# Action not called when I use f:convertNumber?

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

I have a simple form. when I use f:convertNumber in inputText, action never called. but convertNumber comments, there is no problem and action will be called.
It's my code?

```
<h:form id="Form">
        <p:growl id="grwl4FSingleField" sticky="false" autoUpdate="true"/>
        <h:panelGrid columns="3" style="width: 70%" id="panel">

            <p:outputLabel for="terminalId" value="Terminal Id:" />
            <p:inputText id="terminalId" value="#{formBean.terminalId}"
                    required="true" requiredMessage="Please enter Terminal Id."
                    converterMessage="You should enter number for this field.">
                <f:convertNumber  integerOnly="true" type="number" groupingUsed="false"/>
                <p:ajax update="terminalIdMsg grwl4FSingleField" event="blur"/>
            </p:inputText>
            <p:message for="terminalId" id="terminalIdMsg"/>

            <p:commandButton id="Btn" actionListener="#{formBean.payCaller}" ajax="true"
                             value="Pay" update="grwl4FSingleField"/>

        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

and my bean have a simple setter and getter for terminalId with Integer type. FormBean is in request scope

I'm using primefaces 3.5 and jsf 2.0

What is the problem??

Comment: In other words, conversion has failed (the default consequence is, the action will be blocked). Didn't you see any conversion error message?

Comment: No, I don't see any faces message that should be viewed by p:growl or any log in tomcat logs

Comment: Could you give us your primefaces & JSF version and the code of your formBean? And could you give us the input you do to provoke the behaviour?

Comment: I edited question for more information taht you wanted.Thanks